# Html checkbox input size is wrong

Tags: html, css, asp.net

[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebEeE.png)
Im working on a asp.net site for work and I need to have inputs both text and checkboxes. My current solution is as follows:

```
<form method="post" style="width:100%">
    <table style="padding:5px; width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap; width:1%">Printer name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PrinterName" value="@Request["PrinterName"]" style="max-width:100%; width:100%" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap">Model:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Model" value="@Request["Model"]" style="max-width:100%; width:100%" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap">Location:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Location" value="@Request[" Location"]" style="max-width:100%; width:100%" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap">IP:</td>
            <td>
                <table style="margin:0px; padding:0px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px"><input type="text" name="IP" value="@Request["IP"]" style="max-width:100%; width:100%" /></td>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:1%">
                            <div><input style="margin:0px; padding:0px" type="checkbox" />QuickIP</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap">MAC(XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX):</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="MAC" value="@Request["MAC"]" style="max-width:100%; width:100%" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="Sumbit" style="max-width:100%; width:100%" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The checkbox is not reporting the correct size(IE and Chrome) and the text is not being kept inside of the space either.

The aim is to have the text directly beside the checkbox, and both fo those being in line as small as possible to the right of the text input. How would i achieve that without this strange bug ?

Edit: in my testing i had switched the textbox and the button as wel las added a height in the style of the checkbox, those have been corrected now

Edit2: Added in a picture of what shows up right now

Comment: Checkbox is already on the right of the textfield.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/4qkyr5uc/

Comment: I get stuck on the loading bounce from here; but either way as it stance they are on the right, but there is a very large area taken up by whitespace that i cant get rid of, the text beside the box is way outside of the table footprint and i cant get it to stay Inside the table.

Comment: added in a picture so you cna see what i mean

Comment: Which browser (with version) you are facing this issue? It seems like working for me on Chrome (69.0.3497.100).. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkpnV.png

Comment: IE and Chrome; Chrome seems to have fixed itself through trying otu different things, but the IE still displays as the picture linked shows

Comment: As for IE version: it is 11.2515.14393.0

Comment: I don't find any problem in IE as well.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TtYv.png. I think you should share your CSS as well.. You might be doing something wrong in your CSS..

Comment: Thats very strange. There is the default asp.net bootstrap Css nothing else that isnt applied here. Tried going through with he dev Tools nad removing everything that was being applied still no dice..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to remove `height: 1%` from

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;width:1%">
  <!-- remove the height from the style below -->
  <div><input style="margin:0px; padding:0px; height:1%" type="checkbox" />QuickIP</div>
</td>
```

This will render the checkbox next to the "QuickIP" text

Take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/asteinheiser/pen/YJXoBE).

Comment: Woops. had added that in as part of testing, but it does not resolve the issue either way. (Updated the code above to reflect that, and that i had attempted to exchange the order fo the textbox and checkbox)